# Matlab Brackets as Variable Declaration

Tags: matlab

I am a bit confused by how the brackets in Matlab work when declaring a matrix. For example, what does this mean?

```
[~,data]=prices_init;
```

In the Matlab documentation it says the following:

```
Capture three output arguments from a function:
[C,iA,iB] = union(A,B)
```

I am confused by how you actually capture these output arguments. Which variable do you use to refer to the array created? C, iA, or iB?

Comment: They are 3 different outputs, explained in the ['Outputs' section of `union`'s documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html#btcme1d-8). The first example [ignores the first output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html) of `prices_init`.

Comment: This is the documentation on the function call syntax: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/call-a-function.html